# Chess Opening Puzzle App

Tags: opening, puzzles, android

I like chess puzzle apps. But they all focus on the end or middle game.

The reason is clear: In the opening there is no single truth.

But there is some common sense what's good and what's not.

Is there an android app which help me train the best opening moves?

I found some apps for openings, but they work like this: First you need to choose the name of the opening, then you train.

I don't care for the names.

I want to see a chess board and then it is my turn to do the next move.

I don't want to choose a particular opening first.

Comment: Do you want to learn opening principles and piece development, or do you want to memorize opening lines?

Comment: @Saibot I am unsure. Don't know. I want to think, have fun and learn.

Comment: What about chess puzzles? Try lichess.org for playing chess and solving tactical puzzles.

Comment: @Saibot I know that there are great puzzles for middle and end games. This question is about chess puzzles for **openings**.  Can you choose opening puzzles on lichess.org?

Comment: There are quizzes to find good developing moves in openings, in lichess.org

Comment: Have you tried lichess yet? I think their opening quizzes are what you looking for.

Comment: @Saibot I first thought you mean the lichess app. Now I tried the lichess.org web page. Yes, there are opening puzzles. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

GM Nigel Davies has a training DVD on opening tricks&traps, I'm sure you will like it.

http://en.chessbase.com/post/nigel-davies-tricks-traps-vol-1

Also, in lichess.org, there are quizzes for finding good development moves in openings, I recommend you to take a look.

By the way, lichess.org can be used by it's [Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lichess.mobileapp&hl=tr), if you don't want to use it from website.

Answer (score 1):

I found an other way to solve my question:

The android app DroidFish can show the recommended opening moves.

You can add a custom button to the GUI to show/hide the recommended opening moves from the book.

It is not like a real puzzle, but similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about an app for this, but I think you'll love this book: **Modern Chess Self Instructor Book 1** by *Victor Pozharsky*
It's a puzzle book which is based on opening moves.

Answer (score 0):

Lichess.com has an excellent application just for finding the best moves on a given opening.

It is kind of like Tactics Training, but with openings.
You don't even have to register or pay anything either!

Although a lot of the openings it gives you are pretty obscure, it helps develop a good 'opening intuition'.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons people learn openings and their names/variations is to build a personal "book" or repertoire. Also as you said, there is no single truth/good move in the opening; the choices are many.
So you can either settle down on some popular openings and then use opening Apps to learn more or you can just play against the mobile using any popular app and are every turn ask the App for a hint.
That way you would make the best possible move and even have fun playing a complete game.

Asim
Developer of some Android Chess apps